# Entered values of datagrid are different than from a textfile

Tags: c#, byte, binarywriter

I need some insight about the following case.

I have written a program which reads japanese characters (`Encoding 932`).
When they are displayed in the Data Grid, there is an option to change the values, entering standard `ASCII` characters.

Next step is saving those new values bytewise to the file. It does work and the characters are changed indefinitely as the target platform (videogame) **displays them differently**.

What's not working is, saving the changes first in a text file, so I can patch the target file later on.
When I start the patching mechanism, I read the text file with the stored values (new value is stored as a hex number).
The new value is been written, but the is no change to the target file.

Are the stored values of the Data Grid that much different than stored in a text file as a hex number?

Comment: Make sure you specify the encoding in all reads and write of files.  Standard ASCII encoding remove non printable characters.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did work with a list, but now with an ObservableCollection and now it works. I set the encodings too btw.